# Essential questions about our site

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

Looking for help I found [this post](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/help/whats-beta) about the beta sites essential questions that need to be answered. Now, that we will go to [public beta](https://bioinformatics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/40/48) soon, we could decide when to answer them:

> 1. Are questions about {subject} on or off topic?

I think we have been discussing this in meta, through several posts: [Post 1](https://bioinformatics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35/should-we-allow-questions-about-biology), [post 2](https://bioinformatics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/38/is-it-okay-to-ask-questions-regarding-being-a-bioinformatician), [post 3](https://bioinformatics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1/what-sort-of-questions-are-appropriate-for-bioinformatics-se) and [post 4](https://bioinformatics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/47/please-refrain-from-closing-proper-but-imperfect-questions-so-quickly).

> 2. What should our FAQ contain?

It might be too early to propose a FAQ, but we haven't discuss it yet.

> 3. How should we tag questions about {subject}?

We have been discussing with *-seq technologies: [Post](https://bioinformatics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5/let-s-standardise-some-tags)

> 4. Who should the moderators be?

Recently [Pro tempore moderators post](https://bioinformatics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/60/accepting-nominations-who-should-moderate-this-site)

> 5. What’s the “elevator pitch” for our site?

I think [these guides](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/07/10/the-7-essential-meta-questions-of-every-beta/) might be helpful, but we haven't discussed it yet.

> 6. What should our logo and site design look like?

Too early? But we could start thinking about it.

> 7. How do we promote our site?

In [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58858/bioinformatics) some users have been discussing efforts to promote the site in reddit, facebook and twitter.

When should start discussing about questions 2, 5 and 6?

Comment: Thanks for posting this! However, I think each of these points should be discussed in a separate post. That way, we have a specific post to link to in future about each of the issues raised here. As for the FAQ usually is a collection of questions on the main site tagged with the `faq` tag. Those will come as we grow. We might want to open a meta post eventually to collect them though.

Comment: @terdon Yes, I was doubting too if it was too broad, I have edited to make it less broad. By asking about the timing of the discussions

Answer (score 1):

I am afraid the page you linked to is not really that relevant any more. It is in [urgent need of an update](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/201776/203101). An updated version (although "unofficial") can be found here:

[The Real Essential Questions of Every Beta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/223674/203101)

I would strongly suggest we all give it a read, it is useful information.

That said, let's see:

1. Are questions about {subject} on or off topic?

   As you pointed out, this has started already and it will be an ongoing discussion and will probably last as long as the site itself. The scope of a Q&A site is constantly evolving as more edge cases appear and we will continue to refine it by posting on meta. The scope will eventually be defined by the collection of [scope](/questions/tagged/scope) questions.
2. What should our FAQ contain?

   I think that's out of date. There's not really any such thing as a speciic FAQ as far as I know. There is a meta tag [faq](/questions/tagged/faq) but only moderators can use that so it's something we can revisit after we have moderators and after we have some more content on meta.

   On the main site,  what we have is the "frequent" tab in the main page which you see when you click on "Questions":

   [image: question page header]

   That is, as far as I know, populated by the system automatically and not something we need to worry about.

   That said, once we do start having enough traffic to have repeated questions and find a set of them that are asked very often, we can set up a collection of "Canonical Questions" with good answers and then use them as duplicate targets.
3. How should we tag questions about {subject}?

   [Daniel Sandage](https://bioinformatics.meta.stackexchange.com/users/96/daniel-standage) and other users have been doing a great job opening such discussions already. Again, this is going to be an ongoing process which will last as long as we do. After we've been using the site for a while, certain tagging guidelines will emerge naturally and others will be hashed out here on meta as we have ben doing these past few days.
4. Who should the moderators be?

   Already being dealt with. The SE community managers will be selecting the pro-tem mods from among those who have been nominated. Then, if and when we graduate from a beta site to a full blown member of the SE community, we will have [full democratic elections](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/135360/203101) and will get to vote for our own mods.
5. What’s the “elevator pitch” for our site?

   This one deserves its own question where we can propose different ones and vote on each. Perhaps we can do so in a few days. I think it might be a bit too early now while our scope is still being defined.
6. What should our logo and site design look like?

   Again, I think the information on the page you linked to is dated.  In my experience, SE comes up and proposes a (usually very nice) design when we get close to graduation and that's when the community gives feedback. Of course, if anyone has any ideas they are welcome to post them as questions on meta and maybe the SE designers will take them into account but they are professionals and tend to do a pretty good job. I'd just wait until they show us what they come up with and discuss it then.

   Note that no site gets any personalized graphics before full graduation so we have loads of time for this.
7. How do we promote our site?

   This one we may as well discuss, I guess. We've already have done so in [Bioinformatics Chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58858/bioinformatics) last week when we feared we might not make it into public beta. Once again though, I think it basically boils down to each of us sharing the news with the people we think might be interested using whatever means we find most comfortable.